# There are finitely many maps on nonnegative integers satisfying $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

How to show that there are finitely many maps $\phi:\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\to \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ with the property that $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$ for all $a,b\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.